# How to read from and write to files using NASM for x86-64bit

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I have a NASM program for 64bit Linux system which works with standard I/O devices and it looks something like that:

```
section .data

prompt      db  "Enter your text: ", 10
length      equ $ - prompt
text        times 255 db 0
textSize    equ $ - text    

section .text
global main
main:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, prompt
    mov     rdx, length
    syscall         ;print prompt

    mov     rax, 0
    mov     rdi, 0
    mov     rsi, text
    mov     rdx, textSize
    syscall         ;read text input from keyboard

    mov     rcx, rax  ; rcx  - character counter
    mov     rsi, text ; a pointer to the current character starting from the beginning.

   ****
exit:
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall
```

I need the program to read from and write to the files, but I can't find anywhere which syscalls has to be used and how they should be used to achieve these results. So, I am wondering if someone of you could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use system calls "open" and "close":

Open a file under 64-bit Linux:

```
rax = 2
rdi = pointer to NUL-terminated filename
rsi = something like O_WRONLY  or  O_WRONLY|O_CREAT
rdx = file flags if creating a file (e.g. 0644 = rw-r--r--)
syscall
now rax contains the file hanle
```

Close a file:

```
rax = 3
rdi = file handle
syscall
```

Reading/writing from/to a file:

```
rax = 0 or 1 (like keyboard/screen in/output)
rdi = file handle (instead of 0/1)
...
```

---

See *[Opening file modes in x86 assembly Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558966/opening-file-modes-in-x86-assembly-linux)* for where to find definitions for the flags, e.g. in  `asm-generic/fcntl.h` which defines them in octal.  (NASM uses different syntax for octal literals than GAS and C; you want `0q100` rather than `0100`.)

`O_RDONLY` happens to be `0` on Linux, so it's the "default" if you forget to include one of `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`.  (The [`open(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) says the `flags` parameter must include one of the three.)

Use `strace ./my_program` to decode the args you actually pass to system calls, and their return values (in RAX).  A bad pointer will result in `-EFAULT` for example, or trying to write a read-only file descriptor will result in `-EBADF`.

Answer (score -2):

;this program is only overwrite the result.txt

;to write it on bottom you need to lseek to the end

section .data

prompt db "Enter your text: ",10

length equ $ - prompt

text    times 255 db 0

textsize equ $-text

fname db "result.txt",0

fd dq 0

thefox dq 0

global _start

section .text

_start:

mov al,1

mov dil,al

mov esi,prompt

mov dl,length

syscall

mov al,0

mov dil,al

mov rsi,text

mov rdx,textsize

syscall

mov [thefox],rax

mov rax,2

mov rdi,fname

mov rsi,0102o

mov rdx,0666o

syscall

mov [fd],rax

mov rdx,[thefox]

mov rsi,text

mov rdi,[fd]

mov rax,1

syscall

mov rdi,[fd]

mov rax,3

syscall

mov rax,60

syscall

Comment: `mov al,1` - That assumes that RAX=0 to start with, which only happens to be true when Linux starts a *statically* linked executable.  (To avoid info leaks; even that's not actually guaranteed by the ABI).  If you made a dynamically-linked executable out of this code, all the registers (except stack pointer) would have non-zero garbage once execution reached your `_start` after running code from `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` first.  This isn't https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ so don't bother trying to save a couple bytes by taking advantage of Linux static-executable register init state,

Comment: You're defeating your `mov al,1` code-golfing later when you do `mov rax,3` instead of `mov eax,3`, and by using 64-bit operand-size for the file descriptor.  A Unix `fd` is an `int`, 32-bit aka dword.  It also doesn't need to get saved to memory, just keep it in a register.  Also, use `default rel` to make things like `mov rdx,[thefox]` use more efficient and compact RIP-relative addressing.

Comment: Another bug: `thefox dw 0` only reserves 2 bytes, but you load 6 bytes from it with `mov rdx,[thefox]`, instead of `movzx`.  You do only store 2 bytes from the `read` return value.    (Assuming the first `write` didn't return an error, then your syscall number will be `0xffffff00` and it'll return -EINVAL because you used `mov al,0` after the first syscall.)  Anyway, if someone tried to build on this code, and put other non-zero stuff after it in `.data`, that load into RDX as the length would return garbage.  Again, the obvious solution is just to keep the length in another register.

Comment: If you see the end of my codes its ended with exit syscall (rax=60). Thats pure asm thats static executable. My codes already compiled and no error with it. BUT if you work with dinamic exec thats will be mistake. I hope thats explain how it work already compiled and run with no error. There is no error if you do as i do coz i already run it.

Comment: Code in Stack Overflow answers should be usable in general, as part of a larger program.  That's not the case for this code, it only works at the `_start` of a static executable.  If you want to optimize for code-size this way, you should document any required pre-conditions (like zeroing registers) with comments.  And yes, if you read my first comment it should be clear that I understand exactly why this does work in a static executable.  I downvoted because it's not a good example of how to write code, and has multiple bugs (like loading 8 bytes from a `dw 0`) which only happen to work here.

Comment: about bug of thefox that contain of word....i edited. I think you are right, my codes work if there is no mistake when its run, but if there is error when open some file that writeprotected thats might be will crash my codes. Thanks alot.

Comment: its ok to downvote me. But its like there is no full example to explain it clearly. I only want to help.

Comment: I'd be happy to upvote this answer if/when the code is a *good* example for future readers, with comments about which parts do what.  (At least on each system call).    I 100% agree that explaining *clearly* is what a good answer should do.  Not some weird code-golfed thing using partial registers that depends on a bunch of registers already being zeroed.  (And if you fix the code-formatting that you broke with your last edit; removing the backticks and double-spacing turned it into a mess that's much less nice to look at.)

Comment: Also, like I said, file descriptors are `int` so you should be using dword size (EAX) to store / load the `fd`.  (There's also no need to save it to memory in the fist place, you have enough registers).  So there are a bunch of weird unexplained choices in how your code works, especially choice of operand-size for call numbers and lengths, and for system-call return values.  Using the same size as the documentation + ABI indicate is usually good, like `int` => dword for file descriptors.  And in general dword is the natural efficient operand-size for x86-64.

Comment: i like if someone else edit my code. Not because i am not capable to edit it but i will let someone else to do that because i am clearly enough to explain it. Like or not like it. This is it. Thx anyway for the question. And thx to peter cordes too about his corrections.