# Shellcode using metasm to read a file and and write it to stdout

Tags: assembly, nasm, shellcode

So I have the below. Have been gleeming what I can off various tutorials on the web but am stuck now with the important of reading the file and writing it to stdout

```
_start:
    jmp call_shellcode
shellcode:
    ; Call sys_open
    pop rsi
    mov rax, 2
    mov rdi, rsi
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall

   ; Call sys_read on the file handle and read it into rsp
   ; Call sys_write to write the contents from rsp to stdout (1)
  
    ; Call sys_exit
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 99
    syscall
call_shellcode:
    call shellcode
    db '/var/random.txt',0
```

Comment: BTW, this isn't going to work as shellcode for most code-injection vulnerabilities; many of your instructions involve a `0` byte in their immediate operands.  If you don't need to avoid zeros, you could just use a RIP-relative LEA instead of the jmp/backwards-call/pop trick which avoids 0s in the `call rel32`.  (But avoiding zero byte is a modification you can do after implementing the basics with read and write syscalls.)

Comment: Near duplicate of [How to read from and write to files using NASM for x86-64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20133698) which shows a `read` syscall and explains the args.  Obviously you can just use `mov rsi, rsp` if you want to overwrite an arbitrary amount of stack space, with some large size.  (Or you can use Linux-specific `SYS_sendfile` to copy data from a file to another FD without having to bounce it through a user-space buffer, if you don't want to eventually do something between reading and writing.  Check the man page for args, same calling convention as all syscalls.)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? "I'm stuck" doesn't tell us anything useful to help you.